# Can a blech be placed on a stove on shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work

If a person forgot to put a blech on the stove, can he do it on shabbos? Sources would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There are different opinions (see [here](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Permissible_ways_to_heat_up_food_on_Shabbat#cite_note-33) for example).

The Shemirat Shabbat KeHilchata 1:23 and 1:38 permits it, only if the fire is not that strong enough to make the blech "red-hot".

In [footnote 33](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Permissible_ways_to_heat_up_food_on_Shabbat#cite_note-33:%7E:text=Sh%E2%80%9Dt%20Zera,%E2%86%91), Halachipedia says:

> Sh”t Zera Emet 3:26 permits one to put a metal tray (with small holes) on a fire on Shabbat and then do Hachzara based on S”A 318:8 where he brings the dispute whether one can do Hachzara on an empty over the fire and rules like the lenient opinion. Chazon Ish 37:11 argues that actually placing the metal sheet on the fire is the forbidden act of Mavir based on Rambam (Shabbat 12:1, 9:6) who says that one who heats metal to mold it violates Mavir. Even though S”A 253:3 writes that on Shabbat day one can put a empty pot on a fire (and then return a pot that was on the fire right before), Chazon Ish explains that S”A is talking about a earthenware pot and not metal. However Nishmat Adam 20:1, Kesot HaShulchan (134 pg 42), Sh”t Shevet Halevi 1:91, Sh”t She’ilat Shaul 29, Chazon Ovadyah (Shabbat 1 pg 55), and Sh”t Tefilah LeMoshe 1:59 (pg 647) argue that in our case the tray won’t become hot as a coal or hot enough to be reshaped and so it should be permitted. Shemirat Shabbat KeHilchata 1:23 and 1:38 permits covering the fire on Shabbat as long as the fire isn’t strong enough to make the tray red-hot.

See also this [article](https://torah.org/torah-portion/weekly-halacha-5770-kiseitzei/?printversion=1).

Comment: This is all assuming there isn't a problem of Kibui. Classically, a "blech" meant you were covering coals in a fireplace which is surely forbidden since it puts them out.

Comment: @DoubleAA but the question specified that it's about a stove

Comment: @msh210 Some stoves burn wood.

Comment: Cool. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KennyXiong no problem! Please let me know if this answer answers your question or if you need anything else.

Comment: Thank you. Shabbat shalom